# Calculate Growth rate in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a last year sale and some currant year sale so I want calculate growth rate in F3 Cell number and I have used this formula `=SUM(D3:D4)/SUM(C3:C4)-1` to calculate the growth rate.

Something like this:

[image]

If I add some Sale in Current year then I drag down sum formula range in growth rate formula:

[image: Please See Pic]

I want automatic Calculate growth rate if I add new value in Current year and then automatic collect Sale from last year in same currant year sale and calculate growth rate.

**Note:** Growth rate will be Calculate day by day...

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you're expecting as a result but my crystal ball tells me you need to research **$** (absolute range reference). `=SUM(D$3:D4)/SUM(C$3:C4)-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain what you require, but this might help:

```
=SUM(D3:D14)/SUM(OFFSET(C3,,,COUNT(D3:D14),1))-1
```